# How to copy file to another machine through terminal?

Tags: ssh

I have Ubuntu 10.04 running through VMPlayer. And I have another machine (Asus RT-N16 router). I am able to connect to the router with telnet and see its file system.
How can I copy the file from the local machine (file is */home/user/helloworld-c*) to the router (folder */tmp/mnt/discb_1*)?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Is there possibility to connect via SSH? Maybe you should consider "scp" utitlity. It's very simple, look to the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/scp.1.html):

```
man scp
```

The very basic usage:

```
scp remote_user@remote_host:/path/to/remote/file /path/to/local/file
```

and vice versa:

```
scp /path/to/local/file remote_user@remote_host:/path/to/remote/file
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! How can I do the same with the whole folder?

Comment: Use "-r" option: scp  -r user@host:/path/file /path/local. Please, mark the answer as accepted if it works.

Comment: Just look to manual page for scp (in terminal, type "man scp"). There is a lot of more options.

Comment: How can I copy folders also with files, this command just copying only files

Comment: @LA_ you can zip all files.

Answer (score 16):

To copy a non empty directory from the remote computer to your computer:

```
scp -r remoteusername@192.168.1.56:/home/vrc/Desktop/www /home/ourusername/Desktop
```

To copy a file just exclude the `-r` option:

```
scp remoteusername@192.168.1.56:/home/vrc/Desktop/file1 /home/ourusername/Desktop
```

To copy from your computer to the remote computer, just switch the location and destination in the previous example.
For more info do `man scp`.

Answer (score 11):

**Another way you can do: ( via pem file )**

If you want to use `pem` file and you are `ROOT` user:

**1. root user:**

```
sudo scp -i ~/servers/your-key.pem ~/your-local-source-path/your-local-file.txt root@00.00.00.11:/you-server-destination-path/
```

note the colon `:` between server `IP` and destination path.

if I can't logged in with `root` user, see step 2.

**2. standard user:**

suppose you are `ubuntu` user with standard privileges.

```
sudo scp -i ~/servers/your-key.pem ~/your-local-source-path/your-local-file.txt ubuntu@00.00.00.11:/home/ubuntu/
```

this will put the file in home directory.
then login to remote sever with standard user. and do

```
sudo su
```

you'll switched to `root` user. then move the file to destination directory

```
mv /home/ubuntu/your-local-file.txt /you-server-destination-path/your-local-file.txt
```

I often encounter this problem, therefore sharing an alternative way to get the job done !

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you.